# How to test addError message?

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Is there any way to get the message that is included in the addError method in the trigger in order test its contents in the test class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try/catch` block where you get the message from the `Exception` as follows.

```
String msg;
try {
    update ent;  // here you trigger the .addError('')
} catch (Exception e) {
    msg = e.getMessage();
}
```

And value of the `msg` will be

```
"common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 5501l000000e18YAAQ; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Account cannot be changed as there exists cases with this entitlement.: []"
```

Where the `Account cannot be changed as there exists cases with this entitlement.` is the `addError` message. With this you can assert the `msg` as this.

```
System.assert(msg.contains('Account cannot be changed as there exists cases with this entitlement.'));
```

Comment: +1 You can also Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(records, false); or whatever, and examine the results to make sure the message is present.

Comment: also: `sobject.hasErrors()` method